# inequality for the infinite sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I have a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n+1)}$ which converges, consider $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|}{(n+1)^{2}})^{2}$, I can show it also converges. Now I want to show $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|}{(n+1)^{2}})^{2}$ is less than or equal to $M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n+1)}$, where $M$ is a positive real number. I have tried to expand $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|}{(n+1)^{2}})^{2}$ into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{(n+1)^{4}}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m\neq n}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}||a_{m}|}{(n+1)^{2}(m+1)^{2}}$, and obtain the first sum is less than $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n+1)}$, but I don't know how to deal with second sum, is there a way to bound the second term? Is $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|}{(n+1)^{2}})^{2}/\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n+1)}$ even bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|a_n|} {(n+1)^{2}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {|a_n|} {\sqrt {n(n+1)}} \frac {\sqrt {n(n+1)}} {(n+1)^{2}}$. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{n}(n+1)} {(n+1)^{4}}<\infty$.